# Making a 2x image for retina display

Tags: ios, retina-display, retina

If I have an image that at normal resolution (72dpi) is 50x50, and I need to make a 2x resolution image for retina display, do I make it...

- 50x50 at 144 dpi?
- 100x100 at 144 dpi?
- 100x100 at 72 dpi?

I need to appear the same size.  In other words, it can't look twice as large on a retina screen. (I'm new to this.)

Comment: Is it a vanilla image like a picture, or an image for an icon?

Comment: It's a black and white (grey scale) logo.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "dpi" in UIImage display. Just make the 2x version 100x100, twice the point count as the 1x version.

Comment: Ok. And then it will display at half the size?

Comment: It will display as 50x50 _points_, because it will be a 100x100 _pixel_ image on a double-resolution screen, that is, a screen with two pixels per point. See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797719/image-asset-size-in-xcode-interface-builder/42798062#42798062

Comment: If you're looking for a simple way to resize images from a command line utility, I've found ImageMagick very handy. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php You can install it via Homebrew https://brew.sh

Comment: @Adrian He shouldn't resize a 50x50 to 100x100 to serve as the 2x image. It will look terrible.

Comment: @matt Right. Scale down the big image, not scale up the small.